# The graph of a function from a group G to G is normal in GxG if and only if

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It can be easily shown that if $f$ is a function from a group $G$ to itself is a group in $G \times G$ iff the function is a homomorphism. If $f$ is also normal in $G \times G$ what else can be said about such function? I showed that the function needs to have image contained in the center of $G$. Is it also a sufficient condition for it to be a normal subgroup? ($f$ is viewed as being a subset of $G \times G$)

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: $f$ just also be constant on conjugacy classes of $G$. Pretty sure with your center condition these are sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of giving this question an answer, I will move @Robert Chamberlain's comment into the answer section, as well as flesh it out. I've marked it as community wiki so as to not take credit for their work.

---

> $f \unlhd G \times G$ iff $f : G \to G$ is a homomorphism so that
>
> 1. $\text{Im}(f)$ is central in $G$
> 2. $f$ is constant on conjugacy classes

First, let's show left to right:

$$(a,b)(g,f(g))(a,b)^{-1} = (aga^{-1}, bf(g)b^{-1}) = (aga^{-1}, f(aga^{-1}))$$

From this we see $bf(g)b^{-1} = f(aga^{-1})$ for every $a,b \in G$.

First taking $a = e$ shows $f(g) = b f(g) b^{-1}$ for every $b$. Thus $f(g)$ is central for each $g$, and $\text{Im}(f)$ is central.

Next, taking $b = e$ shows $f(g) = f(aga^{-1})$ for every $a$. Thus $f$ is constant on conjugacy classes.

Now, right to left:

$$
(a,b)(g,f(g))(a,b)^{-1} = 
(aga^{-1},bf(g)b^{-1}) \stackrel{(1)}{=} 
(aga^{-1}, f(g)) \stackrel{(2)}{=}
(aga^{-1}, f(aga^{-1})) \in f
$$

Where in $(1)$ we have used $\text{Im}(f)$ is central, and in $(2)$ we have used that $f$ is constant on conjugacy classes.

---

I hope this helps ^_^